# Print only when user keywords match section keywords

Tags: awk

I have a bash script calling `awk`.  I want to test whether `ukeys` contains elements in array `kaggr`, if so setting `display=1`.

My problem is how to avoid the array test when `keywords` or `ukeys` are empty.  What can I do?

```
  awk -v ukeys="$keys" -v beg_ere="$beg_ere" -v pn_ere="$pn_ere" -v end_ere="$end_ere" \
    '$0 ~ beg_ere {
       title=gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0);
       subtitle=gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0);
       keywords=gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0);  

       nk = split(keywords, kaggr, ",");
       nu = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",");
       for (i in uaggr) {
         match=0;
         for (j in kaggr) {
           if (uaggr[i] == kaggr[j]) { match=1; break; }
         }
         if (match == 1) { display=1; break; }
       }
       next
     }
     $0 ~ end_ere { display=0 ; print "" }
     display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
    ' "$filename"
```

I am passing `keys="resource"` to match values in `keywords`.  But when `keys` is empty, I do not want to match anything in `keywords`.

Comment: Interesting, but do you have a question or a problem? If you're asking people to review your code (and comment on it), it is more appropriate to post such on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. Else update your question with current sample output vs the expected output from the same inputs. Good luck.

Comment: Yes, I have a problem.  I want to introduce a similar test (currently implemented in bash) to be included in the awk statement in order to set `display=1;`.

Comment: Please read the section here titled [How to turn a bad script into a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info) and reduce the size of your question. Good luck.

Comment: Will look into that then.

Comment: *"how to avoid the array test"* ... You are capturing `nk` and `nk`, so you can wrap each `for` loop with a test like `if (nu) { for ... if (nk) { for ... } }` OR am I missing something? Without sample input and expected output, I don't want to spend more time on this. Good luck!

Comment: You are not missing anything.

Answer (score 1):

Just to clarify, if the array "ukeys" or "keywords" are empty you want to skip the for-loop? Would this approach solve your issue?

```
 awk -v ukeys="$keys" -v beg_ere="$beg_ere" -v pn_ere="$pn_ere" -v end_ere="$end_ere" \
    '$0 ~ beg_ere {
       title=gensub(beg_ere, "\\2", 1, $0);
       subtitle=gensub(beg_ere, "\\3", 1, $0);
       keywords=gensub(beg_ere, "\\4", 1, $0);  

       nk = split(keywords, kaggr, ",");
       nu = split(ukeys, uaggr, ",");
       if(length(keys) > 0 && length(keywords) > 0) { # if either arrays are empty, skip this part
           for (i in uaggr) {
             match=0;
             for (j in kaggr) {
               if (uaggr[i] == kaggr[j]) { 
                   match=1; break
               }
             }
             if (match == 1) {
                 display=1; break
             }
           }
           next
       }
     }
     $0 ~ end_ere { display=0 ; print "" }
     display { sub(pn_ere, "") ; print }
    ' "$filename"
```